# Реализация системы доступов

Tags: laravel

Недавно начали пытаться перевести старый десктоповский проект на веб. Выбрали вариант отдельно rest-бек на Laravel и отдельно фронт на vue. Уровень владения теорией пока удручающе низок. Буду благодарен за любой совет.

Реализую систему доступов. 
Имеется: Таблица групп. Таблица документов. Таблица связей группа_доступа-документы. На данный момент представляю реализацию следующим образом:
После авторизации пользователя, в сессии бека сохраняется список групп, в которые входит пользователь(как непосредственно, так и через группы) (или же хранить нецелесообразно, лучше каждый раз вычислять?). При написании метода get в контроллере фильтр по реквизитам документов дополняется ограничением по наличию связи искомых документов и сохраненных групп. 
Это наверное жуткий костыль? Как положено это делать штатными возможностями Ларавела?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня была подобная реализация, при добавлении нового пользователя, в базе добавлялось поле роли и группы. В админке можно было настраивать эти роли и группы (т.е. куда можно войти, что можно скачать, лимит на скачивание и.т.д).
После авторизации с общей базы считывались группы которые есть, потом через array_key_exists искал в этой группе, группу данного пользователя и выводил уже всё необходимое (Ссылки и.т.д).